# Create a setup file in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, installation, windows-installer, setup-project

I have a windows form project and I want to create an installation package for this project. How can I create a setup file in Visual Studio 2012 ? My project is without data base.

How to create a Setup package using Visual Studio 2012.NET?

Comment: I install installshield bud dont work corect :( my visual studio don't have setup and deployment , anyone know why ?

Comment: As I've already mentioned in my answer, if you only need a setup file, try ClickOnce. Just right click on the project file in the solution explorer and select "Publish" from the pop-up menu.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Visual Studio setup projects (vdproj) are not supplied with VS 2012](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2011/03/17/visual-studio-setup-projects-vdproj-will-not-ship-with-future-versions-of-vs.aspx)
There are several solutions for you:

- You could use [InstallShield](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kt85ked.aspx) instead.
- If you don't want or
  can't use InstallShield for any reason, you could try [WiX](http://wixtoolset.org/). This
  toolset builds Windows installation packages from XML source code.
- If you only use Windows Presentation Foundation (.xbap), Windows Forms (.exe), console application (.exe), or Office solution (.dll) you could look at [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). To use this you should right click on the project file in the solution explorer and select "Publish" from the pop-up menu.
- Alternatively you can use previous version of Visual Studio (2010).

Comment: If you don't want to move to previous version of Visual Studio, you can move to VS 2013 and then you can use this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2014/04/17/visual-studio-installer-projects-extension.aspx as Dai mentioned below.
Also you could try WiX - http://wixtoolset.org/

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft released the Visual Studio Installer Project extension in April of this year, the catch is it's for VS2013, not VS2012.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2014/04/17/visual-studio-installer-projects-extension.aspx

The 'lite' InstallShield option remains in VS if you need something with more flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

Advanced Installer also has a free version that includes an [extension for VS](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/ai-ext-vs.html). This is a commercial tool but the extension is included in the free edition as I said, for more advanced features you need to purchase a Professional or higher licenses and edit the project direct from Advanced Installer GUI, not from VS. (but you can still use the project in the VS solution, so you get the MSI built at the end of your build process)